# Android Podcasts

Tags: android, podcast

So I've noticed that there are no Android Development podcasts, so I'm thinking that I'd like to start one, with a group of developers, and I would like to know, what would fellow android developers like to hear about? And would you like to take part in creating a podcast? I'm thinking about creating a podcast about once every 1 or 2 weeks. Let me know any thoughts/ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to check this answer as correct, only because since everything is idea based, I don;t think it would be fair to mark one response as correct

Answer (score 5):

A few topics:

1. Some kind of a cool tip per week.
2. A main segment that tells about either news (IE, new SDK, etc) or explains the basics behind some kind of an Android concept (Perhaps things like how to use GPS, bluetooth, challenges of dealing with multiple screen sizes,  etc.). Could also include interviews with famous developers.
3. Perhaps a featured program of the week?
4. A Challenge of the week, something for programmers to practice.

Good luck, it should be quite interesting.

Comment: Great Ideas, I'd love to continue and expand on this topic a little further though, any other ideas? I'd appreciate if you wanted to give me some more in depth ideas, so I can start planning a little bit more, so If you want to shoot me an email, let me know

Comment: Added a few more ideas, hope it helps!

Comment: +1 for "Challenge of the week"

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could talk about various open API's and they can be useful to different types of existing application, and how to implement them on Android

Answer (score 1):

A podcast to receive and show info from Wikipedia, based on user's interest.